# Basic tutorial for multithreading

Tags: multithreading, event-handling

I'm a coding newbie, but I really wanna learn how to do multithreading and event handling.

Does anyone know of any good tutorials out there, or can they explain it to me in a nutshell?

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind?

Comment: Is he doesn't have a language in mind, I like a discussion of multi-threading in Java (not to hijack the question)

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking C++, specifically MS Visual Studio. Java would be fun.. after I "master" C++.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to learn it using C# as a background language, take a look on [Joseph Albahari free ebook on the subject](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

After your comment about learing it using C++ I'd suggest you to use [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html). You can find a tutorial on how to get started and use it at [Dr. Dobb's website](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401518)